# Navigation SubMenu can't get centered

Tags: html, css

I have made a navigation so far and something like this below.

HTML

```
<div id="topNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">View</a></li>
                <li class="drop">
                    <a href="#">You</a>
                    <div class="dropdownContain">
                        <div class="dropOut">
                            <div class="triangle"></div>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Plan </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Plan </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Plan </a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#topNav {width: 100%;}
#topNav ul {text-align: center;}
#topNav ul li {cursor: pointer;-webkit-transition: padding .05s linear;-moz-transition: padding .05s linear;-ms-transition: padding .05s linear;-o-transition: padding .05s linear;transition: padding .05s linear;}
#topNav ul li.drop {position: relative;}
#topNav ul > li {display: inline-block;}
#topNav ul li a {border:1px solid #CCC;line-height: 80px;padding: 0 20px;height: 80px;color: #777;-webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;-moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;-ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;-o-transition: all .1s ease-out;transition: all .1s ease-out;}
#topNav ul li ul li {width: 125px;padding: 10px 5px;margin: 0px 10px;color: #777;text-align:center;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-transition: background .1s ease-out;-moz-transition: background .1s ease-out;-ms-transition: background .1s ease-out;-o-transition: background .1s ease-out;transition: background .1s ease-out;}
#topNav ul li ul li a {border:none;line-height:0;padding:0;height:auto;background-color:#FFF;color:#666;}
.dropOut .triangle {width: 0;height: 0;position: absolute;border-left: 8px solid transparent;border-right: 8px solid transparent;border-bottom: 8px solid white;top: -8px;left: 50%;margin-left: -8px;}
.dropdownContain {width: 160px;position: absolute;z-index: 2;left: 50%;margin-left: -80px; top: -400px;}
.dropOut {width: 160px;padding-bottom:10px;background: white;float: left;position: relative;margin-top: 0px;opacity: 0;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);-webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;-moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;-ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;-o-transition: all .1s ease-out;transition: all .1s ease-out;}
.dropOut ul li a {text-align:center;}
.dropOut ul li:hover {background: #f6f6f6;}
#topNav ul li:hover .dropdownContain { top: 65px; }
#topNav ul li:hover .underline { border-bottom-color: #777; }
#topNav ul li:hover .dropOut { opacity: 1; margin-top: 8px; }
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mcf4kbz4/).
I tried to use `text-align:center;` , `vertical-align:middle;` there and the problem is subMenu is not really looking good. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing to reset the padding assigned by default to UL elements

```
#topNav ul {
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;   /* this one was missing */
    /* margin:0; /* uncomment if needed  */
}
```

***[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/mcf4kbz4/1/)***

Answer (score 0):

Every ul element have some default padding at left side to show the bullits, so when you set list style to none then you have to remove your left padding to show your items at the center,
Just set the left padding of your ul that makes your dropdown menu to 0 it will work

I have added a class attribute 'subm' to your ul that makes your dropdown menu, and applied paddding-left: 0; it will work now.

```css
#topNav {width: 100%;}
#topNav ul {text-align: center;}
#topNav ul li {cursor: pointer;-webkit-transition: padding .05s linear;-moz-transition: padding .05s linear;-ms-transition: padding .05s linear;-o-transition: padding .05s linear;transition: padding .05s linear;}
#topNav ul li.drop {position: relative;}
#topNav ul > li {display: inline-block;}
#topNav ul li a {border:1px solid #CCC;line-height: 80px;padding: 0 20px;height: 80px;color: #777;-webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;-moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;-ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;-o-transition: all .1s ease-out;transition: all .1s ease-out;}
#topNav ul li ul li {width: 125px;padding: 10px 5px;margin: 0px 10px;color: #777;text-align:center;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-transition: background .1s ease-out;-moz-transition: background .1s ease-out;-ms-transition: background .1s ease-out;-o-transition: background .1s ease-out;transition: background .1s ease-out;}
#topNav ul li ul li a {border:none;line-height:0;padding:0;height:auto;background-color:#FFF;color:#666;}
.dropOut .triangle {width: 0;height: 0;position: absolute;border-left: 8px solid transparent;border-right: 8px solid transparent;border-bottom: 8px solid white;top: -8px;left: 50%;margin-left: -8px;}
.dropdownContain {width: 160px;position: absolute;z-index: 2;left: 50%;margin-left: -80px; top: -400px;}
.dropOut {width: 160px;padding-bottom:10px;background: white;float: left;position: relative;margin-top: 0px;opacity: 0;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);-webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;-moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;-ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;-o-transition: all .1s ease-out;transition: all .1s ease-out;}
.dropOut ul li a {text-align:center;}
.dropOut ul li:hover {background: #f6f6f6;}
#topNav ul li:hover .dropdownContain { top: 65px; }
#topNav ul li:hover .underline { border-bottom-color: #777; }
#topNav ul li:hover .dropOut { opacity: 1; margin-top: 8px; }
.subm{
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="topNav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">View</a></li>
    <li class="drop">
     <a href="#">You</a>
     <div class="dropdownContain">
      <div class="dropOut">
       <div class="triangle"></div>
       <ul class='subm'>
        <li> <a href="#"> Plan </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Plan </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Plan </a> </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```